# Styles are not applied to the LitElement in Safari/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, lit-element

**Update from 01.2020**: It should be fixed with https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/pull/712

If `undefined` returned from `render` method of `LitElement` during the first render of the component and then lit-html TemplateResult is returned with some css classes (styles are defined in `styles` static getter method), these styles are not applied.

[image]

There is a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PavelKozlov/u2dmy4s1/6/) to reproduce this issue.

If render method returns lit-html TemplateResult after first render of component, then `<style>` tag exists in shadow DOM.
[image]

If render method returns `undefined` after first render, `<style>` tag is missed in shadow DOM and never added even if lit-html TemplateResult in next render call.
[image]

For **Chrome** it works fine. The issue reproduces for **Safari** and **Firefox**.

UPDATE: It should be fixed with https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/pull/712

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions is to make sure you always return lit-html TemplateResult from render method even if it's empty!

```js
render() {
   return html``;
}
```

But I don't fully understand why exactly this issue appears? Could somebody clarify?

Comment: The [documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#render) does specify that `render` must return a `TemplateResult` so the behaviour when returning `undefined` is probably not specified.

Comment: That's true. I'm curious why exactly it behaves differently for different browsers. How these browsers work with web components?

Comment: @abraham, The [documentation](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates) section 'Rendering nothing' specifies: The values undefined, null and the empty string ('') in a text binding all render an empty text node. So I can assume, that these values are acceptable.

Comment: That is the lit-html documentation and doesn't specify how lit-element defineds it's APIs.

Comment: If you look at source code of LitElement [render](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/master/src/lit-element.ts#L223) method, you can see that it returns `TemplateResult` or `void`. But in comment for this method they said `This method must return a lit-html TemplateResult`. So it's a little bit contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate cases of how styling is handled based on Shadow DOM support, via source code:

```
(1) shadowRoot polyfilled: use ShadyCSS
(2) shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets available: use it.
(3) shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets polyfilled: append styles after
```

That's why it can behave differently in different browsers.

LitElement has a method `adoptStyles()`. It applies styling to the element shadowRoot using the `static get styles` property.

In your example, you could call `this.adoptStyles();` after changing the property and it should render correctly.

https://wicg.github.io/construct-stylesheets/#using-constructed-stylesheets

https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/master/src/lib/shady-render.ts#L127

Anyhow, I think you faced a bug within the `update` method of LitElement.

This could solve it: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/pull/849